# Java - Is it common practice to use a hashtable (eg HashMap) to map objects to themselves?

Tags: java, hashmap, treemap

I'm making a java application that is going to be storing a bunch of random words (which can be added to or deleted from the application at any time). I want fast lookups to see whether a given word is in the dictionary or not. What would be the best java data structure to use for this? As of now, I was thinking about using a hashMap, and using the same word as both a value and the key for that value. Is this common practice? Using the same string for both the key and value in a (key,value) pair seems weird to me so I wanted to make sure that there wasn't some better idea that I was overlooking.

I was also thinking about alternatively using a treeMap to keep the words sorted, giving me an O(lgn) lookup time, but the hashMap should give an expected O(1) lookup time as I understand it, so I figured that would be better.

So basically I just want to make sure the hashMap idea with the strings doubling as both key and value in each (key,value) pair would be a good decision. Thanks.

Comment: What would the key be in your map?  Or if the word is the key, what is the value?

Comment: @Paul The word would double as both the key AND the value. Same word object for both. This seems redundant so that's why I asked the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I want fast lookups to see whether a given word is in the dictionary or not. What would be the best java data structure to use for this?

This is the textbook usecase of a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html).  You can use a `HashSet`.  The naive implementation for `Set<T>` uses a corresponding `Map<T, Object>` to simply mark whether the entry exists or not.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like that makes more sense. According to Java's API, it looks like HashSet uses a HashMap internally. Just out of curiosity, do you think HashSet is basically just using the single object I give it on an add() as both the key and value for the internal HashMap?

Comment: @Tim: IIRC, as the value it uses a constant object that is created once and only once (a singleton).  But it's really not that important what it uses, since it will take up the space of a reference either way.

Comment: @Tim:Strange question.What I was wondering about when I learned how it does it, is about the wasted space of the extra bytes for the second value.What does it matter what the second value is?

Comment: I suspect that the key and value in the hashSet implementation are the probably the same reference (as in put(blammy, blammy)), but the actual details are implementation dependant.  Use javap (comes with the JRE) to decompile the hashSet  implementation of your JRE to find out.

Answer (score 1):

If you're storing it as a collection of words in a dictionary, I'd suggest taking a look at [Tries.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) They require less memory than a `Set` and have quick lookup times of worst case `O(string length)`.

Answer (score 0):

Any class that is a `Set` should help your purpose. However, Do note that `Set` will not allow for duplicates. For that matter, even a `Map` won't allow duplicate keys. I would suggest on using a  an `ArrayList`(assuming synchronization is not needed) if you need to add duplicate entries and treat them as separate.

Comment: Wouldn't ArrayList have an O(n) lookup time though since it would have to check each entry in the array?

Comment: while that's true, there is no getting around it if you have duplicates and need to store them separately

Comment: @Mozen: There are many ways around it depending on the requirements of your data type.  One is to use a `MultiMap`, or a `Map<T, Integer>`, or a `Bag`.

Comment: yeah... what I meant was that he couldn't use a `Set` then

Answer (score 0):

My only concern would be memory, if you use the HashSet and if you have a very large collection of words... Then you will have to load the entire collection in the memory... If that's not a problem.... (And your collection must be very large for this to be a problem)... Then the HashSet should be fine... If you indeed have a very large collection of words, then you can try to use a tree, and only load in memory the parts that you are interested in.

Also keep in mind that insertion is fast, but not as fast as in a tree, remember that for this to work, Java is going to insert every element sorted. Again, nothing major, but if you add a lot of words at a time, you may consider using a tree...

Comment: Thanks. I'm confused as to why insertion would be faster in a tree than in a hashSet? Isn't inserting into a hash table (assuming it's a good hash table) O(1), as opposed to O(lgn) insertion time in an ordered tree?

Comment: @Tim Trees are better at memory allocation than hash based data structures because you have to re-index your hash table when it becomes full.

Comment: @Baumann: What do you mean by "when it becomes full"? Doesn't it use linked lists at each bucket which can grow to any size?

Comment: By full I mean when the number of buckets exceeds the capacity of the HashSet.